# QProcess unknown error

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I got strange problem. QProcess just not working!

And error is unknown.

I got global var in header

```
QProcess *importModule;
```

An I got this function ( I tried both `start` and `startDetached` methods btw )

```
    void App::openImport(){
      importModule = new QProcess();
      importModule->setWorkingDirectory(":\\Resources");
      importModule->startDetached("importdb_module.exe");
      QMessageBox::information(0,"",importModule->errorString());
}
```

It jsut outputs that `error is unknown`. Also it wont start other exes like

```
    void App::openImport(){
      importModule = new QProcess();
      importModule->setWorkingDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseHg");
      importModule->startDetached("hg.exe");
      QMessageBox::information(0,"",importModule->errorString());
}
```

What I've done wrong?
And is there other ways to run some `.exe` from my programm?
Or maybe `.bat` files(which runs exes)? (Tried with QProcess too, not working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startDetached()` is a static method and doesn't operate on `importModule` at all.
It starts a process and then stops caring. Thus the error()/errorState() in `importModule` has nothing to do with the `startDetached()` call. What you want is `start()`.
However, as QProcess is asynchronous, nothing will have happened yet immediately after start() returns. You must connect to the `started()`, `error()` and `finished()` signals to learn about the result.

```
connect(importModule, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(importModuleStarted()));
connect(importModule, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(importModuleFinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
CONNECT(importModule, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(importModuleError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
importModule->start(QStringLiteral("importdb_module"), QStringList());
```

Alternatively you can use the blocking wait functions:

```
importModule->start(QStringLiteral("importdb_module"), QStringList());
importModule->waitForStarted(); // waits until starting is completed
importModule->waitForFinished(); // waits until the process is finished
```

However, I strongly advise against using them in the main thread, as they block the UI then.

Comment: oh, but what about pathes? I mean how to set them in that case?

Comment: Ah, forgot to pass the executable name. Fixed.

Comment: oh, thanks, but  I also meant full path to .exe
or it suppose to be like this `QStringLiteral("somepath/importdb_module")`?

Comment: you can specify the full path in there, or modify the PATH via http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocessenvironment.html