# Can't run cmd or python from Qt C++ app (but can run, say, notepad)

Tags: qt

I have followed numerous examples littered around the web for running a python script from a Qt app, but I just cannot get it to work. I've tried this:

[QProcess unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873912/qprocess-unknown-error)

Amongst many other examples.

I have even directly copied examples which other people have said works, but with no success at all. I simply cannot get a python script to run or even launch a cmd window. I can, however, launch notepad.

This, for example is called when I press a button:

```
void MainWindow::test()
{


    qint64 pID;
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/k cd /d " << "c:\path to be opened";
    myProcess->startDetached("cmd.exe", arguments, "", &pID);

}
```

To no avail.

Also, this:

```
QProcess p;

QStringList params;

params.clear();
params.append("C:\\Software\\Qt\\StarLib\\cadstar_workspace_paths.py");
params.append("C:\\Software\\Qt\\StarLib\\TP1268_RDU5.csw");
params.append("C:\\Software\\Qt\\StarLibcadstar_local_user_directories.txt");

p.setWorkingDirectory("C:\\Software\\Qt\\StarLib");
p.setProgram("py");
p.setArguments(params);

p.start();
if (!p.waitForStarted()) {
    ui->textEdit->append("Could not start process");
    return;
}
else
    ui->textEdit->append("The program seems to have started.");
QTime time;
time.start();
while (time.elapsed() < 4000)
        QApplication::processEvents();

p.kill();
p.waitForFinished();
```

With this code, it reports that the application seems to have started, even though it hasn't.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Am happy to post any further relevant information that would help. I'm clearly missing something fundamental here!

Comment: Why not just use `system`?

Comment: Because every single example I'd found of running python from Qt said use process.

Comment: We did a project where we used Python embedded in Qt about half a year ago. We just used the python C-API.